# passing a return type through the calling method in Java

Tags: java, recursion, control-flow

I have to build a connect4 board and I am struggling with the win checking. I know that I could just do it with 400 if else statements & conditionals but I have istead tried to do something a bit cleverer but I can't understand why it's not working:

```
public boolean checkWin() {
    // check horizontal
    for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_WIDTH; x++) {
      if (recursiveCheck(4, x, 0, 1, 0)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean recursiveCheck(int count, int x, int y, int incX, int incY) {
    while (count > 1) {
      if (x + incX < BOARD_WIDTH && y + incY < BOARD_HEIGHT && board[x][y] != 0
          && board[x][y] == board[x + incX][y + incY]) {
        System.out.println("TRUE");
        System.out.printf("x = %d, x+1 = %d", x, x + incX);
        recursiveCheck(count - 1, x + incX, y + incY, incX, incY);
      }
      return false;
    }
    System.out.println("BIG TRUE");
    return true;
}
```

In the case of the recursive method coming back as true I do get the console log

> BIG TRUE

but the `return true;` statement int my `checkWin()` method never fires.

Any ideas?

Comment: it appears that you never call checkWin()?

Comment: Sorry, calling that from :  try {
        // adjust for zero-index
        int input = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()) - 1;
        System.out.println(input);
        board.takeTurn(input, currentPlayer.getId());
        if (board.checkWin()) {
          System.out.printf("Well done!");
        }
        turn++;
        displayBoard();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }

Comment: @Matthew Player, could you add more information like what value you have passed in BOARD_WIDTH and BOARD_HEIGHT variable and where you have defined your 2-d array board?

Comment: How do I format code in the reply?

Comment: class Board {
  public static int BOARD_WIDTH = 7;
  public static int BOARD_HEIGHT = 6;
  private int[][] board;

  public Board() {
    this.board = new int[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];
  }...

Comment: Have you learned anything about the debugger yet?

Comment: Not really, am just loggin the output at different points. Will have a look at that

Comment: repl here: https://repl.it/@mplayer78/ConnectNmk2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your recursiveCheck function with the print statement removed

```
private boolean recursiveCheck(int count, int x, int y, int incX, int incY) {
    while (count > 1) {
      if ((x + incX < BOARD_WIDTH && y + incY < BOARD_HEIGHT && board[x][y] != 0
          && board[x][y] == board[x + incX][y + incY]) {
        recursiveCheck(count - 1, x + incX, y + incY, incX, incY);
      }
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It seems to me that this recursiveCheck function will always return false first if you pass in a count greater than or equal to 2. You are calling

```
recursiveCheck(count - 1, x + incX, y + incY, incX, incY);
```

inside your if-statement, but you are not doing anything with the result you get from calling the function. Therefore the if statement will eventually evaluate to false. So instead you should

```
return recursiveCheck(count - 1, x + incX, y + incY, incX, incY);
```

instead of simply calling the function in your while loop

Comment: So I am going to try and run the logic through in my head. If I have a board which has a run starting from 0,0 (0-index) then on the initial call to recursiveCheck the arguments passed will be (4, 0, 0, 1, 0), in which case the 1st argument (count) > 1 so the if block will run and as the conditional is met it will make a call to recursiveCheck with arguments (3, 1, 0, 1, 0) and not hit the false return as the function is called before that bit of the code. (3,1,0,1,0) still has count > 1 so it will call the function again and so on until the function is run with (1,3,0,1,0) ...

Comment: whereupon count is not > 1 so the while loop will not run and the true statement (and the BIG TRUE log) will be returned. I am making the assumption that this true return will bubble through all of the calling functions therefore evaluating recursiveCheck to true. Is there a gaping hole in my logic somewhere?

Comment: @MatthewPlayer The true statement will be returned, but the question is, where does it return to? It returns to the previous recursiveCheck call inside the if statement and you are not doing anything with this result. So this line finishes executing and the if statement reaches its end. Then, it returns false to its previous recursiveCheck call and again you are not doing anything with this result. Eventually you will evaluate all the recursive calls without doing anything with the result you get, and finishes the if statement and return false to checkWin()

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I have included the return statement in the call to the recursive function and at that point everything beyond that is short circuited so each recursion in turn will evaluate to true (if there is a connection). Thank you so much. I have been staring at that for a couple of hours!!

Answer (score 0):

Well if the recursive method reached the "Big True" part it should return true. Yet I can't see how would you check for it ? "Big True" is printed so check for the return statment.
Either us a debugger and set breakpoints or simply if you want go with print statements add statments for each output. Like

```
public boolean checkWin() {
// check horizontal
for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_WIDTH; x++) {
  if (recursiveCheck(4, x, 0, 1, 0)) {
    System.out.println("SMALL TRUE");
    return true;
  }
}
System.out.println("SMALL FALSE");
return false;
}

private boolean recursiveCheck(int count, int x, int y, int incX, int incY) {
while (count > 1) {
  if (x + incX < BOARD_WIDTH && y + incY < BOARD_HEIGHT && board[x][y] != 0
      && board[x][y] == board[x + incX][y + incY]) {
    System.out.println("TRUE");
    System.out.printf("x = %d, x+1 = %d", x, x + incX);
    recursiveCheck(count - 1, x + incX, y + incY, incX, incY);
  }
  System.out.println("BIG FALSE");
  return false;
}
System.out.println("BIG TRUE");
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone does a very specific search on the internet and comes up with this question I thought I would include my final (working) code (thanks to MT756 & Bender)

```
public boolean checkWin() {
// check horizontal
int[][] cartesian = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, -1 } };
for (int[] c : cartesian) {
  for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_WIDTH; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_HEIGHT; y++) {
      if (recursiveCheck(Game.connect, x, y, c[0], c[1])) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
}
return false;
}

private boolean recursiveCheck(int count, int x, int y, int incX, int incY) {
while (count - 1 > 0) {
  if (x + incX < BOARD_WIDTH && x + incX > 0 && y + incY < BOARD_HEIGHT && y + incY > 0 && board[x][y] != 0
      && board[x][y] == board[x + incX][y + incY]) {
    return recursiveCheck(count - 1, x + incX, y + incY, incX, incY);
  }
  return false;
}
return true;
}
```

The nested loops aren't as bad as they appear, honest!!